# My squad are Lemmings how do I fix this?

Tags: arma-3

I am currently playing through the Arma 3 campaign and within the first few missions i noticed that my squad seem to be suicidal.

Why is the friendly AI so awful? it makes gunfights almost impossible because the enemy AI stick to strict cover rules or are in the better positions where as my squad stand in front of the cover and just get shot.

Before someone asks me to change the title i would like to add that on 3 occassions multiple members of my squad have walked off of a cliff or from a high place, injuring or killing themselves(thus Lemmings)(*I also know that real lemmings don't do that*)(**thanks disney**)

Is there a way to make the Friendly AI smarter?

Comment: Isn't this all about why did the dev code this this way?

Comment: Yes it looks that is it is his first question, but he is apparently looking for a way to compensate this ingame.

Comment: @Arperum yeah my main point is that i want a solution for it. i just presumed that the solution would answer both points

Comment: edited to remove the that dev related question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post is 8months old at the time I am writing this reply, so it could be that the AI has been updated/improved since the OP.

If not, there are mods which one could run which are meant to improve AI behavior. Have a look on [armaholic.com](http://www.armaholic.com).

Some examples of such mods are:

- [bCombat](http://www.armaholic.com/page.php?id=23969)
- [Fire-Fight Improvement System](http://www.armaholic.com/page.php?id=22096)
- [Vcom AI](http://www.armaholic.com/page.php?id=25381)

But you'll just have to experiment with them to found one that works for you.